# How to resolve a gradle dependency based on coordinates string

Tags: gradle

For my build I need to conditionally resolve a jar depending on some conditional logic. I need the location of the jar file, rather than putting it into the classpath for a particular build or runtime configuration.

```
  if (platform == "jdk8alpn") {
    // Add alpn-boot on Java 8 so we can use HTTP/2 without a stable API.
    def alpnBootVersion = alpnBootVersion()
    if (alpnBootVersion != null) {
      dependencies {
        testCompile "org.mortbay.jetty.alpn:alpn-boot:$alpnBootVersion"
      }
      def alpnBootJar = configurations.testCompile.find { it.name.startsWith("alpn-boot-") } <-- fails here
      test {
        jvmArgs += "-Xbootclasspath/p:${alpnBootJar}"
      }
    }
  }
```

This is now [failing](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15051)

How can I resolve a jar to local path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a configuration just for that artifact

```
def jarPath = configurations.detachedConfiguration(
  dependencies.create("org.mortbay.jetty.alpn:alpn-boot:$alpnBootVersion")
).singleFile
```